# Using Oracle and C#, how can I pass in an array of numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle

This was my attempt:

`cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

`cmd.Parameters.Add("i_num_array_price_list", OracleDbType.Decimal, myItems.Select(c => c.Price).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);`

In oracle, the type is declared as:

`i_num_array_price_list IN num_array,`

and that is defined as:

`TYPE Num_Array IS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER;`

I've tried it as OracleDbType decimal and array, neither worked. Decimal produces this error:

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.`

Any idea how I can get it to accept my array of decimal values?

Comment: Why not keep it as NUMBER? You can insert floating point values into NUMBER fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to make this work using the above definition of my array, so I changed it to an associative array and used the following code:

To define my array:
`TYPE assoc_array_number_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;`

To define my variable:
`i_num_array_price_list IN assoc_array_number_t`

and my C# code:

`cmd.Parameters.Add("i_num_array_price_list", OracleDbType.Decimal, myItems.Select(c => c.Price).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input).CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;`